# How to get all data after callback method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-apis-explorer

I am using node js to get all contact data from Google API.
USing callback function but it takes some time to get data due to run function before next function.
I am very new in node JS can someone help me to sort it out.
I want all data return once the callback function is called.

A contact function to get all contacts.

```
app.get('/contacts', async function(req, res){
  
  // Rendering our web page i.e. Demo.ejs
  // and passing title variable through it
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Tasks API.
     await  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listConnectionNames);
     res.send(full_person_array)
  });
  

})
```

This one is  autorize function that callback listConnectionNames fucntion.

```
function authorize(credentials, callback) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  
    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
      callback(oAuth2Client, id);
      return resolve();

    });

  })
 
}


function listConnectionNames(auth) {
  const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageSize: 50,
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const connections = res.data.connections;
    if (connections) {
      console.log('Connections:');
      connections.forEach((person) => {
        console.log(person);
        full_person_array.push(person);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No connections found.');
    }
  });
}
```

How to get all data in contact without get delayed empty data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add returns instead of mapping the result array to fill an other array :

```
function authorize(credentials) {

    const {
        client_secret,
        client_id,
        redirect_uris
    } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    return fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        return oAuth2Client;

    });
}


async function contact() {
    let auth = await authorize(credentials);
    let connections = await listConnectionNames(auth, id);
    console.log(connections); // full result
}
```

Does it helps you ?

Comment: For passing auth, I need to run an authorized function first. so in contact function it wait to get authorized i want to return data onlly once all data is come up

Comment: Yes and authorize is call in contacts function.

Comment: let connections = await listConnectionNames(auth, test);
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Getting Error posted abobe.

Comment: Well, you can delete this line, it's no more used as you call `listConnectionNames` as a callback inside `authorize`

Comment: Yes, so the question is how I can call listconnectiond data after authorize in contact function. Right now data is call but after sometime once all function is call before that empty array return.

Comment: Yes, `authorize` returns `oAuth2Client` and `listConnectionNames` needs this to call the API. So you can't execute `listConnectionNames` without waiting for `authorize` result beore. I just added the line you have to put inside the `contact` function

Comment: Yes, but can we wait in the contact function till I get the full data without returning an empty one.

Comment: Okay, I edited my code to provide a solution using `await `instead of `callback`, I let you check this

Comment: let auth = await authorize(credentials);
             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: await not work like this way.

Comment: `await` works in `async` function that why I defined `contact` as `async function` ;)